# How to change type from array to primitive in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to change a column type from `integer[]` to `integer`. The table has no row in it and I've already dropped the default.

```
alter table user alter column book_ids type integer USING book_ids::integer;
ERROR:  cannot cast type integer[] to integer
```

I could only found how to change type from `integer` to `integer[]` but not the other way around.

Comment: The array is a single element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr[1]` is the first element of `arr`.

```
alter table user alter column book_ids type integer USING book_ids[1];
```

Comment: omg you saved my day! thank you so much. i'll accept your answer after 10 minutes